# Hide-When doesnt work when a document is changed

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

Im facing a problem with a hide-when formula of an editable field in lets say Document A. The hide-when formula includes a @DbLookup statement, where a field of Document B is read. Dependent on that field, it is hidden or shown.

When I open the Document A, it works just fine and the editable field is hidden. Then I go back to Document B and change the value of the field so the field shows in Document A it is still hidden. Only when I go back in the Notes Designer and save the form of Document A again the hide-when formula works correctly again.

So everytime I change the value of the field in Document B, I have to save the form of Document A again for the hide-when formula to work correctly.

Note that I use @If and @True/@False in my hide-when formula, as it is not that simple as I've explained above.

Any solution in order to make the hide-when formula work correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "NoCache" to first parameter of `@DbLookup("":"NoCache"; ... )`.
This will read the data from your Document B every time not just at first call (or after changing form).